# Is there a simpler way to achieve a reference without creating a variable first?

Tags: go

Is there a way to avoid instantiating a variable first and then assigning it to a struct which is expecting some property to be a reference value, like in the example below?

```golang
type Example struct {
  Active *bool `json:"age,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
  active := false
  e := Example {
    Active: &active,
  }
}
```

A simple function like the one below(`Ref`) would remove the need to first create a variable and then use it in the struct, but I am not sure if I won't eventually shoot myself in the foot in the future because of it.

```golang
type Example struct {
  Active *bool `json:"age,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
  e := Example {
    Active: Ref(true),
  }
}

func Ref[T any](val T) *T {
  return &val
}
```

Comment: As of now, there is not a simpler way to do it. See [proposal: expression to create pointer to simple types](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45624). It's OK to use a `Ref` function. This is mentioned in this thread: https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/mKJbGRRJm7c/m/38gGtL5dNb0J.